# Streamlit error: tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a Streamlit dashboard that shows data from a Kafka topic:

```
from queue import Queue
import streamlit as st

@st.cache_resource
def queue_init():
    queue = Queue()
    return queue

queue =  queue_init()

while True:
    # blocks here
    data = queue.get()
    if data:
        st.line_chart(chart_data)
```

The queue is populated from an external Kafka client. The dashboard was working fine, but all of a sudden I started getting hundreds of exceptions like the one below:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-8415' coro=<WebSocketProtocol13.write_message.<locals>.wrapper() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:1085> exception=WebSocketClosedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1087, in wrapper
    await fut 
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    raise WebSocketClosedError()
tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
```

The streamlit version is 1.22 and the streamlit configuration is below:

```
[browser]
gatherUsageStats = false

[server]
enableStaticServing = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m using an AWS EC2 instance to run my Streamlit app, and i’m not using any venv to install Streamlit and other dependencies. So the packages were installed in /.local directory. and when i try to run the app i was facing the same error as below

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", 
line 1090, in wrapper raise WebSocketClosedError() 
tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
```

The Solution was changing the "websocket_ping_timeout" value to 300 (default value will be 30) under the tornado settings in the below path

```
/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/server/server.py
```

Example snippet:
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGtS.png)